# Strange code that compiles with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++

The following code compiles successfully with g++ 4.8.1:

```
int main()
{
    int(*)();
}
```

It looks like a simple declaration of a pointer to function:

```
int(*f)();
```

It doesn't compile with clang 3.4 and vc++ 2013.

Is it a compiler bug or one of dark places of the standard?

---

#### List of similar strange code pieces which compile fine with g++ 4.8.1 (updated):

1. `int(*)();`
2. `int(*);`
3. `int(*){};`
4. `int(*());`

[Live example with these strange code pieces](http://ideone.com/yGG2yZ).

**Update 1:** [**@Ali**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341970/ali) added some interesting information in the comments:

> All 4 cases give a compile error with clang 3.5 trunk (202594) and compile fine with gcc 4.9 trunk (20140302). The behavior is the same with `-std=c++98 -pedantic`, except for `int(*){};` which is understandable; extended initializer lists only available with `-std=c++11`.

**Update 2:** As [**@CantChooseUsernames**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1462718/cantchooseusernames) noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015482/strange-code-that-compiles-with-g/23019886#23019886) they still compile fine even with initialization and no assembly is generated for them by g++ (neither with nor without initialization) even without any enabled optimization:

1. `int(*)() = 0;`
2. `int(*) = 0;`
3. `int(*){} = 0;`
4. `int(*()) = 0;`

[Live example with initializations](http://ideone.com/5Ugc92).

**Update 3:** I was really surprised to find that `int(*)() = "Hello, world!";` compiles fine, too (while `int(*p)() = "Hello, world!";` doesn't compile, of course).

**Update 4:** It is fantastic but `int(*){} = Hello, world!;` compiles fine. And the following extremely strange piece of code, too: `int(*){}() = -+*/%&|^~.,:!?$()[]{};` ([live example](http://ideone.com/JvqcVL)).

**Update 5:** As [**@zwol**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388520/zwol) noted in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015482/strange-code-that-compiles-with-g?lq=1#comment55044024_23015482)

> This and a number of related syntactic problems are being tracked as gcc [bug 68265](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68265).

Comment: `int(*)();` is like typing `int;` or `int*;` ... That is, you start declaring a variable type, but never name it.

Comment: @ZacHowland, Yeah, but surprisingly, it does balk at `int;`, but not this.

Comment: `fork(3)` - 3 people went to ideone tried to compile `int;`. :)

Comment: @LeeWhite Unfortunately I am not a language constructor, I just a simple code constructor. :-)

Comment: @ZacHowland Neither `int;` nor `int*` compile with g++.

Comment: @chris I imagine it has to do with the parsing of it.  Seems like it is a bug in g++ while clang and VS are providing the proper error.

Comment: @Constructor That is my point.  You are effectively doing the same thing ... with a function pointer declaration (stating the type, but never providing a name).

Comment: @ZacHowland, I'd say so, but I'm too clueless about why this would be any different when both declarations work properly with names.

Comment: Currently digging through http://www.eelis.net/C++/grammar.png but can't find it there

Comment: @PlasmaHH that's an amazing picture, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @chris Perhaps we can get Pete Becker to chime in, but my hunch is that it is a bug in the g++ parsing of this (non-useful) line.  Alternatively, it could simply be ignoring the non-useful line.

Comment: @Streppel: Thanks go to eelis for compiling the dotty file from the standards grammar annex. Since he also fed that to geordi (his c++ irc evaluation bot), and geordi fails on identifying anything there, I would assume it doesn't exist anything int the grammar that reflects it.

Comment: FWIW, all 4 cases give a compile error with clang 3.5 trunk (202594) and compile fine with gcc 4.9 trunk (20140302). The behavior is the same with `-std=c++98 -pedantic`, except for `int(*){};` which is understandable; extended initializer lists only available with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @Ali Thank you. I have tried also `-pedantic-errors` flag but g++ still compiles them even with it.

Comment: @Constructor Oh, yes, I have forgotten to mention: I am using `-pedantic` as well. Excellent question, I am curios what answers you will get!

Comment: @PlasmaHH Is there one of those for C? Or any other language for that matter?

Comment: @Ali I think you can be interested in my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033043/is-it-a-new-c11-style-of-comments).

Comment: @Constructor If I had the time, I would build gcc from source again (with a fresh checkout of course). If this behavior is still present, I would submit a bugreport. Unfortunately, I am busy... :(

Comment: This and a number of related syntactic problems are being tracked as gcc [bug 68265](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68265).

Answer (score 15):

According to the C++ Standard (p. #6 of section 7 Declarations)

> 6 Each init-declarator in the init-declarator-list **contains exactly
>   one declarator-id**, which is the name declared by that
>   init-declarator and hence one of the names declared by the declaration

So it is simply a compiler bug.

The valid code could look as for example (apart from the function pointer declaration showed by you) though I can not compile it with my MS VC++ 2010.

```
int(*p){};
```

It seems that the compiler you are using for testing allows declarations without a declarator-id.

Also take into account the following paragraph of section 8.1 Type names

> 1 To specify type conversions explicitly, and as an argument of
>   **sizeof, alignof, new, or typeid**, the name of a type shall be
>   specified. This can be done with a type-id, which is syntactically a
>   declaration for a variable or function of that type that omits the
>   name of the entity.

Comment: Can it be not initialization statement but something else so g++ compiles it?

Comment: @Constructor In my opinion it is a declaration.

Comment: Please, see my edit to the question. What can you say about it?

Comment: It is extremely strange but `int(*){}` compiles with g++, too.

Comment: OK, but why then simple `int;` or `int*;` don't compile?

Comment: @Constructor Are you trying to find all weird bugs of g++? :) What is the point of that piece of code?

Comment: @Constructor Because they did not contain a declarator. I think that for int * the compiler consideres a declarator only when it is enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: @BЈовић No, I just happened to run into them. :-) And I want to understand are they really bugs or not.

Comment: @Constructor I think the difference exists due to the grammar of the abstract-declarator. For example one of the rules is 
noptr-abstract-declarator:
noptr-abstract-declaratoropt parameters-and-qualifiers
noptr-abstract-declaratoropt[ constant-expressionopt ] attribute-specifier-seqopt
( ptr-abstract-declarator )

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just found yet another piece of strange code (number 3 at the list, see the edit of a question). What can you say about it?

Comment: I think you should add your considerations on why this code compiles (about parenthesis and related part of C++ grammar) to your answer.

Comment: I have just discovered that `int(*){}() = -+*/%&|^~.,:!?$()[]{};` compiles fine, too! What do you think about it? See live example in the new question update.

Comment: @Constructor I think that it is a consequence of the compiler bug.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. But it is a very interesting bug if it allows g++ to compile such code.

Comment: gcc extension to allow censored swearing outside of comments.

Comment: @Yakk In fact it is a new style of comments. :-) See my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033043/is-it-a-new-c11-style-of-comments).

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure how much this helps, but I tried the following (clang 3.3, g++ 4.8.1):

```
using P = int(*)();
using Q = int*;
P; // warning only
Q; // warning only
int(*)(); // error (but only in clang)
int*;     // error
int(*p)(); // ok
int *q;    // ok
```

On the other hand, everything compiles fine in g++ 4.8.2 and 4.9.0. I have no clang 3.4, unfortunately.

*Very roughly*, a declaration [iso section 7] consists of the following parts in order:

1. optional prefix specifiers (e.g. `static`, `virtual`)
2. base type (e.g. `const double`, `vector<int>`)
3. declarator (e.g. `n`, `*p`, `a[7]`, `f(int)`)
4. optional suffix function specifiers (e.g. `const`, `noexcept`)
5. optional initializer or function body (e.g. `= {1,2,3}` or `{ return 0; }`

Now, a *declarator* roughly consists of a name and optionally some declarator operators [iso 8/4].

Prefix operators, e.g.:

- `*` (pointer)
- `*const` (constant pointer)
- `&` (lvalue reference)
- `&&` (rvalue reference)
- `auto` (function return type, when trailing)

Postfix operators, e.g.:

- `[]` (array)
- `()` (function)
- `->` (function trailing return type)

The above operators were designed to reflect their use in expressions. Postfix operators bind tighter than prefix, and parentheses can be used to change their order: `int *f()` is a function returning a pointer to `int`, whereas `int (*f)()` is a pointer to a function returning `int`.

Maybe I am wrong, but I think these operators cannot be in the declaration without the name. So when we write `int *q;`, then `int` is the base type, and `*q` is the declarator consisting of prefix operator `*` followed by name `q`. But `int *;` cannot appear by itself.

On the other hand, when we define `using Q = int*;`, then declaration `Q;` is fine by itself because `Q` is the base type. Of course, because we are not declaring anything, we may get an error or a warning depending on compiler options, but this is a different error.

The above are just my understanding. What the standard (e.g. N3337) says is [iso 8.3/1]:

> Each declarator contains exactly one *declarator-id*; it names the identifier that is declared. An *unqualified-id* occurring in a *declarator-id* shall be a simple *identifier* except for the declaration of some special functions (12.3 [*user-defined conversions*], 12.4 [destructors], 13.5 [overloaded operators]) and for the declaration of template specializations or partial specializations (14.7).

(notes in square brackets are mine). So I understand `int(*)();` should be invalid and I cannot say why it has different behaviour in clang and different versions of g++.

Comment: Thank you. What can you say about the updated list of strange pieces of code?

Comment: I am afraid, not much. Except that they all compile in all versions of g++ I have, but not clang. Again, they compile either if you add a name or define a type alias first (of course, `{}` is an initializer and not part of the type).

Comment: If a name is added they obviously become valid C++ constructions, I think.

Comment: I have just discovered that `int(*){}() = -+*/%&|^~.,:!?$()[]{};` compiles fine, too! What do you think about it? See live example in the new question update.

Comment: @Constructor It gets better and better! And I thought *cheats* were only for games... now it seems compilers can have them, too! Too bad I can't cast another vote :-)

Comment: @MattMcNabb What do you mean? Could you explain, please?

Comment: There's a unix utility called [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) that outputs a text description of a C declaration. For example, `int foo[4]` generates `declare foo as array 4 of int`. Originally it was meant to help people understand complicated declarations.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thank you for your explanation. And you may be interested in my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033043/is-it-a-new-c11-style-of-comments).

Comment: @iavr I discovered that it is not initialization. See my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033043/is-it-a-new-c11-style-of-comments).

Answer (score 6):

You can use this: http://gcc.godbolt.org/ to view the assembly..

```
int main()
{
    int(*)() = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Generates:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Which is equivalent to:  `int main() {return 0;}`
So even with NO optimization, gcc just doesn't generate assembly for it.. Should it give a warning or error? I have no clue but it doesn't care or do anything for the unnamed func pointer.

However:

```
int main()
{
    int (*p)() = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

With no optimization will generate:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    $0, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

which allocates 8 bytes on the stack..

Comment: Good idea! Thank you. And what about `int(*)() = 0;`?

Comment: No assembly either. It won't assign to the unnamed func ptr. If you try assigning 1, same thing.. No assembly generated.

Comment: It is very strange but `int(*)() = "Hello, world!";` compiles fine, too. While `int(*p)() = "Hello, world!";` doesn't.

Comment: I have just discovered that `int(*){}() = -+*/%&|^~.,:!?$()[]{};` compiles fine, too! What do you think about it? See live example in the new question update.

Comment: LOL? That looks like a completely messed up parser problem if I ever saw one.. That should without a doubt give an error.. C doesn't accept any of this stuff: https://ideone.com/GaxlGI

Comment: C doesn't accept even `int(*);` and `int(*)();`. Last fantastic code works only in g++ with `-std=c++11` flag (it is possibly a strange kind of syntax of brace-initialization).

Comment: I discovered that it is not initialization. See my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033043/is-it-a-new-c11-style-of-comments).