# Is it a new C++11 style of comments?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, comments

While I was trying to understand why [the code like `int(*)();`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015482/strange-code-that-compiles-with-g) compiles fine with *g++* I discovered even more strange thing:

```
int main()
{
    int(*){} Is it C++11 or any other language?
}
```

This code compiles fine with *g++ 4.8.1*, see [live example](http://rextester.com/RJBG96221) (flags: `-std=c++11 -pedantic-errors`). Neither *clang 3.4* nor *vc++ 2013* compile it.

**Is it a new C++11 style of comments which is supported only by *g++*? Or a compiler bug?**

---

Here is what I found out about such style of "comments":

1. Usual structure of comment (parts which can be omitted are enclosed in brackets `[ ... ]`):

   ```
   int // or another valid C++ type
   (*) // or another sequence of '*' and/or '&' characters with nonzero length
   {"[Comment header]"}
   [Comment body]
   {[Comment footnote]}
   ```
2. Instead of using footnote terminating symbol `;` can be used: `int(*){} Comment ;`.
3. If the comment is a last construction in a block `{ ... }` both terminating symbol and footnote can be omitted: `{ int(*){} Comment }`.
4. Allowed characters are figures, English letters and characters from the following list: `- + * / % & | ^ ~ = . , : ! ? $ ( ) [ ] < >`.
5. Following characters are not allowed inside comment body or footnote: `; { } # @`.
6. Character literals `'...'` and string literals `"..."` are allowed inside comment body or footnote, but symbols `'` and `"` themselves can not be used separately.
7. Usual C++ comments `// ...` and `/* ... */` work fine inside new "comments". Preprocessor directives, macros, digraphs and trigraphs work fine, too ([live example](http://rextester.com/IBZU47423)):

   ```
   #define TerminatingSymbol ;

       int(*) ??< %> // a pair of trigraph and digraph
       "This is a string" // string literal
   #if 1
       Comment
   #endif
       TerminatingSymbol
       std::cout << "Hello, ";
       int(*){} /* Character literal: */ 'c' <% ??>
       std::cout << "world!" << std::endl;
   ```
8. I was not able to understand how floating point literals work inside such "comments".

---

[The following code sample](http://rextester.com/OKUY17236) illustrates the capabilities of new "comments":

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    void(*){} do not try this float; // simple C++ keywords are allowed, of course
    std::cout << "1";
    int(&){"Allowed characters"}
    - + * / % & | ^ ~ = . , : ! ? $ ( ) [ ] < > ; // ';' itself is not allowed
    std::cout << "2";
    char(************************************)
    {"William Blake wrote:"}
    Tyger! Tyger! burning bright
    In the forests of the night,
    What immortal hand or eye
    Could frame thy fearful symmetry?
    {"The Tyger", 1794}
    std::cout << "3";
    float(*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*)
    {"Some formulas"}
    2 x 2 = 4
    pi ~= 3.145926 ...
    E = m * c ^ 2
    a ^ n + b ^ n != c ^ n, n > 2
    {42}
    std::cout << "4";
    unsigned(*(*(*(*(*(*(*(*(*(*())))))))))){}
    It is a last comment
}
```

Comment: No, this isn't a "new C++11 style of comments", the language standard (§ 2.8) is clear on this.

Comment: @0x499602D2 But it is a very strange bug, isn't it?

Comment: It should be the same parsing g++ bug that you other question highlight.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't think it is the same because such "comments" don't work in pure C++ style: `int(*)(Comment);` etc. Only in C++11 mode with syntax like brace-initialization: `int(*){} Comment;`. But it is close to my other question bug, I agree with you.

Comment: @MichaelBurr not a duplicate but a follow-up, see the link in the first line of the question.

Comment: This and a number of related syntactic problems are being tracked as gcc [bug 68265](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68265).

Comment: @zwol Thank you for your information.