# Why am I able to assign a function reference to an anonymous function pointer variable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code compiles just fine and I'm not sure why. Can someone please explain to me why this is legal?

I am using g++ (Debian 6.1.1-10) 6.1.1 20160724 to compile.

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    using std::cout;

    int (*) (int, int) = &sum;
    cout << "what" << '\n';
}
```

**Addendum**

The following program compiles fine using g++ version 5.4.0 but fails to compile in gcc.

```
int main()
{
    int (*) = 20;
}
```

Comment: That's an irrelevant detail. It's a pointer. It's being assigned to an anonymous function pointer. But "int = 7;" doesn't compile. Neither does "int *=nullptr;". There's probably a most vexing parse's cousin, somewhere in here.

Comment: This also compiles `void foo();`  ...  `int (*) (int, int) = &foo;` - something strange is going on.  (g++ 5.1.0)

Comment: Forget that. `int (*)(int, int);` also compiles.

Comment: Please add compiler info to the question.

Comment: And also `int (*) (int, int) = 5.3;` (trying to avoid decay to pointer on the rhs)

Comment: I am able to compile `int a; int (*) = &a;` using g++ 5.4.0. Strange indeed.

Comment: It compiles under g++ 4.9.2 as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405436/anonymous-functions-using-gcc-statement-expressions The syntax is a GCC extension, not standard C.

Comment: @ToddKnarr  That question is about C, not C++. This applies only to C++. Trying to compile `int (*)(int, int);`: It compiles even with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++98 anon.c`.  Trying to compile it with gcc yields "error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘)’  (gcc 5.3.1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this invalid-looking code compile successfully on g++ 6.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614455/why-does-this-invalid-looking-code-compile-successfully-on-g-6-0)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's very likely to be related to [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68265) reported by Zack Weinberg:

> #### Bug 68265 - Arbitrary syntactic nonsense silently accepted after 'int (*){}' until the next close brace
>
> (From [Why does this invalid-looking code compile successfully on g++ 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33614455/) :)
>
> The C++ compiler fails to diagnose ill-formed constructs such as
>
> ```
>   int main()
>   {
>       int (*) {}
>          any amount of syntactic nonsense
>          on multiple lines, with *punctuation* and ++operators++ even...
>          will be silently discarded
>          until the next close brace
>   }
> ```
>
> With -pedantic -std=c++98 you do get "warning: extended initializer
>   lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11", but with
>   -std=c++11, not a peep.
>
> If any one (or more) of the tokens 'int ( * ) { }' are removed, you do
>   get an error.  Also, the C compiler does not have the same bug.

Of course, if you try `int (*) (int, int) {}` or other variants, it erroneously compiles. The interesting thing is that the difference between this and the previous duplicate/bug reports is that `int (*) (int, int) = asdf` requires `asdf` to be a name in scope. But I highly doubt that the bugs are different in nature, since the core issue is that GCC is allowing you to omit a *declarator-id*.

> [n4567 §7/8]: "Each *init-declarator* in the *init-declarator-list*
>   contains exactly one *declarator-id*, which is the name declared by
>   that *init-declarator* and hence one of the names declared by the
>   declaration."

Here's an oddity:

```
int (*) (int, int) = main;
```

In this specific scenario, GCC doesn't complain about taking the address of main (like arrays, `&main` is equivalent to `main`).